# Xcode Swift text on IOS app doesn't fit on other devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am having a problem with my homework. When I run the program on an iPhone 8s everything works fine, but when I test it on other iPhone devices, the text doesn't fit. I used `AutoLayout` and added constraints as well. The devices starting from left to right is the 8, x, se, 6.

This is the current output:

[image: output]

Comment: Develop for the SE (The smallest screen you need to support) and make sure everything fits there. then you can set up your layouts for other devices to expand on their larger screens.

Comment: oh that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Use a UIStackView. Check out the link for details: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html

Comment: Stack views certainly make it easier to evenly space out your views, but they are not magic. I still recommend building your layouts for the smallest supported screen. That way you know that everything fits.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you might want to do in different places:

`UILabel` has a `numberOfLines` property (which appears in Interface Builder) to allow text to span multiple lines (your constraints usually shouldn't be limiting the height of a label). You might want to use this on the "2 is more than the number ..." line.

There's also a property that allows the label to auto-shrink the font so that text all appears on a fixed number of lines, which you might want to use for your name label. See the "Autoshrink / Minimum font scale" option.

[image: Image showing the UILabel autoshrink option]